# (Spoiler) Witch king + Eltariel side mission disappeared?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-war

In Act 2, after regaining the new ring of power I briefly saw a mission on the ground which mentioned a ring wraith (probably had something to do with Eltariel, the elf lady who saved us from domination in Act 1).

Since I was very interested in how fort sieges go, I decided to complete that quest first. After the fort was conquered, the nazgul mission was gone.

I was wondering if the quest will reappear later or am I screwed for the playthrough (one of the skill customizations mentions the completion of Eltariel missions)?

**Update:**
The first paragraph here http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2017-10-10-shadow-of-war-guide-walkthrough-tips-4823?page=12 mentions

> You may end up unlocking some of them in a slightly different order to
>   how we've listed them as they're dependent on some free-roam
>   activities and quests in other sets, and we'd actually suggest leaving
>   this set of quests until after you've completed Brûz, Carnán, and
>   Gondor - the extra skills and resources unlocked through those will
>   come in handy, and it eliminates any danger of rendering them
>   incompletable.

Not really sure what this means, is this possible to make these quests incompleteable then?

Answer (score 1):

After taking the first fort, the mission disappears from Nurn indeed. But a new one appears in Minas Morgul, and after that is completed, the one in Nurn is playable again.

**Tip:** The easiest way to check the available quests is from the actual "Quests" menu found below the "Army" and "Inventory" menus.

Answer (score 0):

Try making sure your domination is turned in instead of gaining arrows when draining.  I switched it and the quest locked and moved, I went to the quest guide (in game) and it told me, straight out.